# VSCode wants to import library from folder, that doesn't exist because it has been renamed

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I created a folder for my model called platform_Account.

After I created my model `PlatformAccount` there, I decided to rename it to platform_account_model.

When I now try to import my model to other files, I am getting this error:

```
List<PlatformAccount> accountList
The argument type 'List<PlatformAccount> (where PlatformAccount is defined in c:\Users\Wizzel\Desktop\project\lib\models\platform_account_model\platform_account_model.dart)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<PlatformAccount> (where PlatformAccount is defined in c:\Users\Wizzel\Desktop\project\lib\models\platform_Account\platform_account.dart)'
.dartargument_type_not_assignable

list.dart(52, 16): List is defined in C:\Users\Wizzel\fvm\versions\2.8.1\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\core\list.dart

platform_account_model.dart(8, 7): PlatformAccount is defined in c:\Users\Wizzel\Desktop\project\lib\models\platform_account_model\platform_account_model.dart

list.dart(52, 16): List is defined in C:\Users\Wizzel\fvm\versions\2.8.1\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\core\list.dart

platform_account.dart(8, 7):
PlatformAccount is defined in c:\Users\Wizzel\Desktop\project\lib\models\platform_Account\platform_account.dart
```

but the `platform_Account` folder doesn't exist.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can show us how you imported the mode, and where does the model exist on project structure?

Comment: Actually I fixed it by deleting all imports and let VSCode resolve the paths again. 

Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by deleting all import statements and letting VSCode resolve the import paths again.